# Count Consonants Before First Vowel in a String

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-3.4

I'm creating a simple pig Latin translator. Here's what I have so far:

```
while True:
  phrase = input('Translate > ').lower().split()

  for word in phrase:
    if word[0] in 'aeiou': # If the first letter is a vowel
      print(word + '-way') # Add suffix 'way'
    else:
      c = # Number of consonants before the first vowel
      print (word[c:] + word[0:c] + '-ay')
```

How can I make `c` equal to the number of consonants preceding the first vowel in `word` as simply as possible? I'd prefer not to use functions.

EDIT: Yeah, I meant I'd prefer not to define my own functions. Sorry about that.

Comment: "prefer not to use functions" ... what?  Anyway, `c =  next(i for i,c in enumerate(word) if c in 'aeiou')`

Comment: Just FYI: You're using functions.

Comment: I think he means "id prefer not to WRITE functions", which either way is weird

Answer (score 1):

Use [itertools.takewhile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile)

```
 from itertools import takewhile

 c = len(list(takewhile(lambda x: x not in "aeiou", word)))
```

takewhile takes a `predicate` which is the lambda here, it will take the elements while the predicate is `True` so in this case as soon as we come across a vowel the method will stop and return the list of consonants up to that point and we just use the `len` function to check how many consonants are in the list giving us the index for `c`.

Comment: That's perfect! Amazing. Care to explain how it works?

Comment: len, and list and takewhile are all functions :)

Comment: @TehTris, they are builtins not written by me or the OP

Comment: i would have also accepted "functions" obviously u cant take a joke bruh fyi: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html , oh snaps they r functions. i r dum

Comment: @TehTris, what is a bruh?